# Create string from character code

Tags: functions, character-encoding

Is it possible to convert a charcode/keycode to a string?

I want to do this to create variables in a generated equation.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

You can use

```
ToCharacterCode["abcABCαβγ"]
(*
=>    {97, 98, 99, 65, 66, 67, 945, 946, 947}
*)
FromCharacterCode[%]
(*
=>    "abcABCαβγ"
*)
```

To create unique symbols, use

```
Unique["x"]
```